# updated contact-form-7 and now other pages crashed

Tags: wordpress

I have an old site, and my contact-form-7 plugin was corrupted. I upgraded the contact form 7 plugin.

Now all a sudden 1 of my pages looks funny.
I traced it back to the includes/script.js file.
If I use this version:

http://merkaztorah.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.2.1

then I get this funny page :

http://merkaztorah.org/category/programs/

but if I take out the html and change the version back to the old one:

http://merkaztorah.org/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.5.1
the page works like here:

http://merkaztorah.org/what%20we%20offer%202nd-bu.php

What would be in the JS file that would cause my css to fail somewhere? 
How should I get around the problem? Or should I just try to get contact-form-7 version 3.5.1 and put a clean version of that one?

Comment: sorry, that's not my problem. I don't have any jquery errors on my screen

Answer (score 0):

It might be jQuery conflict. Open your website and right click on page and click on inspect element or use shortcut key CTRL+SHIFT+I and on the right top click on errors you will see some errors. If it says $ is not a function then change the $ sign with jQuery where function start. I was facing this type of error and when I change the $ sign with jQuery errors have gone and my script is working.